# SplashScreem no Flutter - Erro com o Bottom Bar

Tags: flutter, dart

Olá, tudo bem?
Então, não consigo fazer a splash screen funcionar na main onde esta o curved Bottom, pois ambos, pelo o que seguir no doc são adicionada na home: do main.dart. Quando adiciono o botão a splash deixa de funcionar e assim para ambos. Como poderia fazer o splash funcionar mesmo com o curved Bottom em meu main?

**Esse é meu código do main junto com o botão adicionei os dois códigos no main, mas não consigo chama-los**

```
 import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';
import 'Anonymos.dart';
import 'Homepage.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: BottomNavBar()));

class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {

  BottomNavBar({Key key,})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  _BottomNavBarState createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  int _pageIndex = 0;
  GlobalKey _bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();

  List pages = [
    MyRoute(
      iconData: Icons.announcement,
      page: Homepage(),
    ),
    MyRoute(
      iconData: Icons.email,
      page: MensagemChat(),
    ),
    MyRoute(
      iconData: Icons.account_circle_outlined,
      page: MensagemChatAnonimo(),
    )
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        key: _bottomNavigationKey,
        index: 0,
        height: 50.0,
        items: pages
            .map((p) => Icon(
          p.iconData,
          size: 30,
        ))
            .toList(),
        color: Colors.indigo[50],
        buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _pageIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      body: pages[_pageIndex].page,
    );
  }
}

class MyRoute {
  final IconData iconData;
  final Widget page;

  MyRoute({this.iconData, this.page});
}

class splashScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  splashScreen({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;


  @override
  _splashScreenState createState() => _splashScreenState();
}

class _splashScreenState extends State<splashScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _introScreen();
  }
}

Widget _introScreen() {
  return Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      SplashScreen(
        seconds: 5,
        gradientBackground: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topRight,
          end: Alignment.topCenter,
          colors: [
            Color(0xff2474fd),
            Color(0xff2882f1)
          ],
        ),
        navigateAfterSeconds: Homepage(),
        loadingText: Text('Carregando',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,),),
        loaderColor: Colors.redAccent,
        styleTextUnderTheLoader: const TextStyle(
            decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.wavy),
      ),
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("Assets/image/Splas.png"),
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ),
        ),
      ),

    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: É complicado tentar imaginar qual o comportamento que está acontecendo e você considera errado, e qual o comportamento seria o certo. Não possui imagens que ilustram? Seu código não é um exemplo viável e executável, não dá pra copiar ele e tentar reproduzir o que você está fazendo. Uma splash screen é uma tela que aparece assim que entramos no app com o objetivo de carregar informações para seu funcionamento, você deve utilizar alguma estratégia de gerenciamento de estado no app para fazer esse controle.

Comment: Compreendo, e obrigado por dedicar o pouco do seu tempo para me ajudar! Fiz o que você indicou e simplesmente criei mais uma arquivo.dart para aonde migrei o Bottom bar. E esta funcionando bem, obrigado!